# Qubit state after this quantum circuit (Hadamard+Eigen Operator+Hadamard)

Tags: quantum-computing

[image]

Could anyone help me with this circuit? I'm trying to walk through this exercise but failed. The first register carries a single bit and the bottom carries an n-qubit state. |ψ_0〉is an eigenstate of operator U, i.e. U|ψ_0〉= e^{2πiθ}|ψ_0〉, where 0 ≤ θ < 1.

What will the probability of measuring 0 on the top register? And what is the output state |ψ_1〉be?

I got the P(0) on the first register = 1/4 (2+cosθ), which seems really strange for me. Is it correct?

Cheers!